# HAProxy check port 443

Tags: haproxy

Is it possible to get HAProxy to health check an SSL / port 443 end point?

The `check port 443` in the config below fails the health check

HAProxy config below

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     50000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    mode                    tcp
    log                     global
    option                  dontlognull
    retries                 3
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout check           5s
    maxconn                 15000


#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# status page.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
listen stats 0.0.0.0:8000
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy
    stats realm HAProxy

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Incoming HTTP -> Admin Redirect Proxy rule
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
listen RedirectToHttps
    mode http
    bind :80
    redirect location https://admin.example.com code 301

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Incoming HTTPS -> Admin Proxy rule
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
listen ToHttps
    mode tcp
    bind :443
    option ssl-hello-chk
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk GET /heartbeat.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ admin.example.com
    server admin-no-check-test     ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-150.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:443 maxconn 5000
    server admin-150-checkport-80  ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-150.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:443 check port 80 maxconn 5000
    server admin-150-checkport-443 ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-150.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:443 check port 443 maxconn 5000
```

Comment: Isn't it `ssl_hello_chk`, with underscores instead of dashes?

Comment: The [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/ssl_hello_chk) is not very clear, but looking online and at another [questions on server fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/236496/haproxy-not-passing-ssl-traffic-in-tcp-mode-unknown-protocol) I link it is 'ssl-hello-chk'

Answer (score 2):

I believe `option ssl-hello-chk` and `option httpchk` are 2 different kinds of checks, but HAProxy will only allow you to use one at a time.  You should choose `ssl-hello-chk` to just check that SSL is there, or use the `httpchk` to check that particular URI, but not both.

Comment: Please could you show me where in the documentation is says that? As I am able to get `ssl-hello-chk` to work with `option httpchk` when doing a `check port 80`

Comment: I haven't been able to find it mentioned in the docs, but there were  a few forum posts where the HAProxy creator mentioned it (for example, http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?10,38918).  There was a more recent one as well, but I can't find it again now.  The port 80 check may work because it ignores the ssl-hello-chk, but I'm not sure.  Does it pass the check if you remove one of the two options?