# HA proxy and keepalived with Splunk search heads

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, splunk

Is anyone using haproxy/keepaliveD as their software load balancer in a HA search head environment?

I am configuring my haproxy.cfg and having some trouble getting sticky sessions and proper load balancing working. This is on a pair of load balancers using haproxy/keepaliveD to 3 splunk search heads.

Here is what i currently have, my sessions seem to stick to spweb3 even when i bring it offline, Possibly i need some sort of check option or cookie but the params i've used only work with http not https.

```
> listen http_proxy :8001
>         mode tcp
>         balance roundrobin
>         stick-table type ip size 200k expire 30m
>         stick on src
>         server srv1 spweb1sb-w1-inf.shared-bo.mtv1.vrsn.com:8001
>         server srv2 spweb2sb-w2-inf.shared-bo.mtv1.vrsn.com:8001
>         server srv2 spweb3sb-w1-inf.shared-bo.mtv1.vrsn.com:8001
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially try some of the other methods for persistence.  One I've used before is `balance source`.  That would use the source IP address to keep traffic going to a particular server while they're all up.  Also, your example lists "srv2" twice; I assume that's a typo?

Comment: Thanks Paul, that was a typo i corrected. I am also trying **balance source** however still getting the sort of sticky behaviour

Comment: Also I am just trying to use HA proxy to do a loadbalance passthrough to the servers running SSL. I am not sure this is the optimal config and cannot find good examples as of yet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: actually this config is working for me http://serverfault.com/questions/236496/haproxy-not-passing-ssl-traffic-in-tcp-mode-unknown-protocol